# Why wouldn't Arrays.sort() work in this case?

Tags: java

In this code I'm trying to sort the arrays so i can check Anagram but it won't sort the variable "smth". when i'm running in test case "Army" , "Mary". Army gets sorted but Mary doesn't get sorted. Any reasons why?? (I'm trying to get the output of sorted Mary so i can ensure the code)

> Your code did not pass this test case.
>
> Input (stdin)
>
> Army Mary Your Output (stdout)
>
> Mary Expected Output
>
> True

```
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word1 = get.next();
        char[] arr1 = word1.toCharArray();
        String smth = get.next();
        
        char[] arr2 = smth.toCharArray();
        
        // Sort both arrays
        Arrays.sort(arr2);
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        for(char ele:arr2) System.out.print(ele);
        
//         // Call the check method and print the result
//         if (check(arr1, arr2))
//             System.out.print("True");
//         else
//             System.out.print("False");
//     }

//     public static boolean check(char[] arr1, char[] arr2) {
//         // Compare sorted arrays character by character
//         for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
//             if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
//                 return false; // If any characters do not match, return false
//             }
//         }
//         return true; // All characters match, so return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), question is unclear. But if I had to make a *guess* (guessing is not good), you want case insensitive sort of the characters, the natural sorting is case sensitive.

Comment: In the future, please don't comment out code that is relevant to the question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upper case and lower case letters are not the same. When you sort letters, all upper case letters are considered "smaller" than lower case letters. E.g. `'Z'` will come before `'a'` but after `'A'`.

You can convert all letters to lower case before your sorting, then it should work as expected:

```java
String word1 = get.next().toLowerCase();
char[] arr1 = word1.toCharArray();

String smth = get.next().toLowerCase();
char[] arr2 = smth.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this one worked. I'll make sure to keep this in mind the next time I sort

Answer (score 1):

The reason why "Mary" is not getting sorted, is because is already in the sorted order. `.sort()` looks at the characters value. Any capitalize char will always have smaller value compared to any lowercase char and this is due their [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) value.

according to the ASCII table the values for

A-Z: 65-90

while for

a-z: 97-122

an easy approach will be to lower case by methods like `.toLowerCase()` and then do `.sort()`

Answer (score -1):

They will be sorted based on ascii encoding. You probably wanted them to be sorted as they were all in lower case. b/c in the encoding, capital letters has smaller values.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it was as you said. It didn't properly sort due to the Lower and upper case difference.